# Android: Null value added to database for username?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext

Within my Android application I have created a game. The details of each game session are written to an SQLite database after every session.

One of the fields within this database is `username.` The username is obtained from the name the user enters in the login screen of the app.

I am having the issue that: the userName is only being entered correctly into the database the first time the game is played.

I.e. if I finish a game session and start the game again to play another,  it is being populated as `Null`. **Why** is this?

**Username entered into the SQLite database such as:**

```java
SignInActivity.getUserName()
```

I.e.:

```java
// Adding the new Session to the database
    db.addSession(new Session(sessionID, "Multiplication", SignInActivity
            .getUserName(), averageMedLevel, medMax, averageAttLevel,
            attMax, score, date, "false",fileNameRaw,fileNameEEGPower,fileNameMeditation,fileNameAttention));
```

**username functionality from Sign in activity:**

```java
public class SignInActivity extends Activity {

    private static String userName; 

    //within on create
    String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
}

//Getter for userName
//Gets userName
    public static String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
```

Is it because I am using? :

```java
String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
```

rather than:

```java
userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString(); //i.e. the static one
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line      `String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();` simply create **new** String object and placed your username there.  Your static field  `private static String userName;` is still empty.

You should use this code

```
SignInActivity.userName = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the line:

`String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();`

appears in the onCreate method as your comment states then this is a local variable that only exists in the context of onCreate.  When getUserName() is called it returns the global variable created with this line:

`private static String userName;`

which has never had a value assigned to it. The key mistake here is that you have created two different variables and assumed they hold the same value because they have the same name.